# Select by attribute, Set innerHTML accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, attributes

How to select by attribute and set result's `innerHTML` accordingly in pure javascript?

```
const texts = [
    {id: 'id01', text='Content 01'},
    {id: 'id02', text='Content 02'}
]

<div data-my-id="id01"></div>
<div data-my-id="id02"></div>
```

End result should be:

```
<div data-my-id="id01">Content 01</div>
<div data-my-id="id02">Content 02</div>
```

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention: It's not efficient to loop over the array since there are hundreds (Maybe thousands) of items. Any way to loop over the querySelector results and set text accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you told your could have a bunch of records on array. I suggest to you to invert the query for this particular case, to something like:

```js
const texts = [
    {"id": "id01", "text":"Content 013"},
    {"id": "id02", "text":"Content 024"}
]

document.querySelectorAll('[data-my-id]').forEach(function(e) {
  e.innerHTML = texts.find(function(g){
    return g.id == e.getAttribute('data-my-id')}).text
})
```

```html
<div data-my-id="id01">Content 01</div>
<div data-my-id="id02">Content 02</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `forEach` to loop over the array and the function `querySelector([data-my-id="specific id"])` to select the element and set the desired text.

*Use the attribute `textContent` instead because you need to set only a text*

```js
const texts = [
    {id: 'id01', text:'Content 01'},
    {id: 'id02', text:'Content 02'}
]

texts.forEach(({id, text}) => document.querySelector(`[data-my-id="${id}"]`).textContent=text);
```

```html
<div data-my-id="id01"></div>
<div data-my-id="id02"></div>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: It's not efficient to loop over the array since there are hundreds (Maybe thousands) of items. Any way to loop over the querySelector results and set text accordingly?

Comment: @stackminu you can jquery, however, always a loop will be executed.

Comment: Any way to do it without jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each text. Find the element with that attribute then change it's inner html.

**EDIT:** I have added the loadHtmlAsyc function so as to not slow down the page load speed. A side effect of this would be the content could potentially load 'randomly' i.e. it will not load one row after the next. But you could load the thousands of items without having to wait for each row to render.

```
const texts = [
  {id: 'id01', text: 'Content 01'},
  {id: 'id02', text: 'Content 02'}
];

for (i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
  let id = texts[i].id;
  let text = texts[i].text;
  let target = document.querySelector(`[data-my-id="${id}"]`);

  loadHtmlAsyc(target, text);
}

function loadHtmlAsyc(ele, html) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ele.innerHTML += html;
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: It's not efficient to loop over the array since there are hundreds (Maybe thousands) of items. Any way to loop over the querySelector results and set text accordingly?

Comment: No to my knowledge, but @Ele might be able to help further. Either way you are going to have to loop through each item in the array to find each element. You could split the texts array into chunks and lazy load them as the user scrolls down the page if your concerned with performance across many thousands of items?